# Cf-deployment fails on bosh-lite VM on Openstack

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have setup a bosh-lite VM on Openstack and now wanted to deploy CF.

cf-deployment fails with the following errors:

```
Task 28 | 06:16:17 | Creating missing vms: router/96e38261-9287-4a69-b526-eb361eb36d84 (0) (00:00:01)
                   L Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Creating VM with agent ID '{{0d5412ff-4140-4c10-9bcc-b82f8b8595ca}}': Unmarshaling VM properties: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string' in 'create_vm' CPI method
Task 28 | 06:16:17 | Creating missing vms: tcp-router/0a492310-b1d7-4092-9f12-7bbdaeafa51f (0) (00:00:01)
                   L Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Creating VM with agent ID '{{e2c6f33e-46b6-4600-a32e-8d113d327dd7}}': Unmarshaling VM properties: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string' in 'create_vm' CPI method
Task 28 | 06:16:25 | Creating missing vms: database/eb7319a4-83af-4463-8cb9-455c2f3689c9 (0) (00:00:09)
Task 28 | 06:16:25 | Creating missing vms: nats/96b398f8-cde3-4c7f-840a-d9abbe66bf4c (0) (00:00:09)
Task 28 | 06:16:25 | Creating missing vms: adapter/29400d43-6d55-49b7-8368-591f4f6357cd (0) (00:00:09)
Task 28 | 06:16:25 | Creating missing vms: cc-worker/fe3e01ce-26ff-45cd-97cd-8b771af7ba7d (0) (00:00:09)
Task 28 | 06:16:26 | Creating missing vms: scheduler/59b98563-5b97-41a3-ac17-9b65998d5091 (0) (00:00:10)
Task 28 | 06:16:26 | Creating missing vms: singleton-blobstore/233fa4c4-7ee0-4b03-83e1-2b958014bad5 (0) (00:00:10)
Task 28 | 06:16:26 | Creating missing vms: doppler/880250b2-9418-4c02-9423-15bf0abe01fb (0) (00:00:10)
Task 28 | 06:16:26 | Creating missing vms: consul/d362ee07-bfc2-4569-a702-6aa9b2806c2b (0) (00:00:10)
Task 28 | 06:16:27 | Creating missing vms: log-api/7387cb18-e24e-4129-be2b-7fecfb2e3170 (0) (00:00:11)
Task 28 | 06:16:27 | Creating missing vms: api/4806fa7e-d2be-4403-b9cc-f4c3cd32269d (0) (00:00:11)
Task 28 | 06:16:27 | Creating missing vms: diego-cell/91a70e59-e815-495b-8f17-f34bfaabb3b2 (0) (00:00:11)
Task 28 | 06:16:28 | Creating missing vms: uaa/c2fb065b-84b7-42fe-85fd-400947ca48f6 (0) (00:00:12)
Task 28 | 06:16:28 | Creating missing vms: diego-api/737edb1d-4e81-48f6-9c22-169e64a3c8bb (0) (00:00:12)
Task 28 | 06:16:28 | Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Creating VM with agent ID '{{0d5412ff-4140-4c10-9bcc-b82f8b8595ca}}': Unmarshaling VM properties: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string' in 'create_vm' CPI method
```

Comment: I assume your question is not related to CFML, which is the ColdFusion Markup Language and has nothing to do with Clould Foundry. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did not intend to add 'cfml' as a tag, but this is related to CF (CloudFoundry)

Comment: Run `bosh task 28 --debug` and review the output.  That should give you some details about the task you listed above.  Also, there seems to be some sort of issue between the CPI & OpenStack, so checking your OpenStack logs would be good too.

Comment: @Daniel Mikusa I see the same errors in the debug log as well. Can it be related to some missing configuration properties (cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string) ?

Comment: Look at the log before the error.  I believe the debug log should also contain the HTTP request/responses to/from your IaaS (if run `bosh task 28 --cpi`).  You should look to see what the IaaS is returning before the error because it's likely an unexpected and possibly erroneous value, hence why the CPI cannot parse it.  If you can find out what's being returned, you might be able to correct the value by adjusting something on the IaaS.  If you know the value, you could also open a bug with the CPI so it handles the situation better.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thanks for the pointers. I tried with the '--cpi' flag and that also highlights a similar error: 

********************
[rpc.JSONDispatcher] 2018/01/09 05:12:29 DEBUG - CloudError response bytes
********************
{"result":null,"error":{"type":"Bosh::Clouds::CloudError","message":"Creating VM with agent ID '{{520ca5e2-1618-4678-99a3-cddc2219a0aa}}': Unmarshaling VM properties: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string","ok_to_retry":false},"log":""}
********************